# Instert an ElementTree.Element as a SubElement

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to create some basic XML in Python. I have a block of XML that I need to access on its own, so I make it as a root Element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Tree

def correction_xml(self):
    correction = Tree.Element('ColourCorrection')
    sop_node = Tree.SubElement(correction, "SOPNode")
    slope = Tree.SubElement(sop_node, 'Slope')
    offset = Tree.SubElement(sop_node, 'Offset')
    power = Tree.SubElement(sop_node, 'Power')
    return correction
```

I also need to insert multiple instances of this part of a bigger XML, so is there a way to insert my `correction` Element into another tree as a SubElement? Somthing like this, except the SubElement factory only accepts a single string, not an Element object:

```
def correction_list(self):
    list = Tree.Element("List")
    item_1 = Tree.SubElement(list, self.correction_xml()) /*insert correction_xml into list as a subelement, keeping its children intact*/
```

Comment: Edited for clarity, the SubElement class doesn't accept an Element object, it only creates a new one.

Comment: Try `append()` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append

Comment: append() and insert() both worked in different ways, thank you @mzjn